# Visual Studio Code's Vue (Volar) extension not showing details of methods and computed properties

Tags: vue.js, vscode-extensions, volar

Visual Studio Code's Vue (Volar) extension not showing details of `methods` and `computed` properties when I hover over my cursor on the method call or computed property call. Here's the screenshot

[image]

and even when I hover over a state variable returning by the `data()` method inside of a `method` that also showing `any` type for that variable and clicking `Ctrl` + `Left Click` also not taking me to the declaration

Please help me fix this :(

Tried chat gpt to get fixes, didn't work, tried reinstalling Volar extension, restarting vs code, disabling other vue extensions, nothting is working

Comment: Check out https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode